# Not displaying in Chrome

Tags: php, wordpress

Trying to add an image in the header of a wordpress site and it is displaying in firefox but not chrome. the other issue is safari has it cut off from the side. Could anyone give me some insight? Here is my code for the header.php 
the website is http://www.cacaobox.com/

```
<?php
/**
* @package    WordPress
* @subpackage Everything
* @since      1.0
*/
?>
<!DOCTYPE html >
 <!--[if lt IE 9]>             
      <html class="no-js ie lt-ie9 <?php    the_field('custom_class'); ?>"     <?php language_attributes();     ?>>     <![endif]-->
  <!--[if IE 9]>                <html class="no-js ie ie9 <?php the_field('custom_class'); ?>" <?php language_attributes();  ?>>            <![endif]-->
     <!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html class="no-js no-ie <?php the_field('custom_class'); ?>" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>   
     <!--<![endif]-->
 <head>
 <meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1" />
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
   <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js">       </script>
    <script src="<?php echo Everything::getInstance()->template_uri; ?>/data/js/selectivizr.min.js"></script>
   <![endif]-->
  <title>CacaoBox</title>
   <?php wp_head(); ?>
      <link rel="icon" href="http://www.cacaobox.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/favicon.png" type="image/png" rel="shortcut icon" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" http://www.cacaobox.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/favicon.png" type="image/png" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/Responsive.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/style.css" />
```

```
 <body <?php
  if (!is_null($background = Everything::io_('layout/background/background', 'general/background/background', '__hidden_ns', '__hidden'))) {
  if ($background instanceof \Drone\Options\Option\ConditionalTags) {
  $background = $background->option();
 }
 echo $background->attrs();
 } else {
  body_class();
 }
 ?>>

<div class="container">
 <div id="wrapper">

  <div id="top-bar" class="outer-container edge-bar<?php if    (Everything::to_('header/top_bar/settings')->value('fixed') || Everything::to_('header/style/settings')->value('fixed')) echo ' fixed'; ?>">

  <?php foreach (array('desktop', 'mobile') as $device): ?>
  <?php
  $items = Everything::to("header/top_bar/{$device}/items", '__hidden', array());
  if ($device == 'mobile' && Everything::to_('header/top_bar/settings')->value('mobile_toggle')) {
   array_unshift($items, 'mobile_toggle');
  }
  if (count($items) > 1):
  ?>

  <div class="container <?php echo $device ?>-only">

   <section class="section">
    <div class="alignleft fixed"><?php

     foreach ($items as $item) {
      switch ($item) {

       case '_':
        echo '</div><div class="alignright fixed">';
        break;

       case 'tagline':
        echo '<span>';
        if ($device == 'mobile') {
         echo Everything::to(array('header/tagline/mobile/text', 'header/tagline/text'), '__hidden', get_bloginfo('description'));
        } else {
         echo Everything::to('header/tagline/text', '__hidden', get_bloginfo('description'));
        }
        echo '</span>';
        break;

       case 'search':
        echo \Drone\HTML::div()
         ->addClass('search-box', is_search() ? 'opened' : null)
         ->add(preg_replace('/ placeholder="[^"]*"/', '', get_search_form(false)))
         ->html();
        break;

       case 'cart':
        echo Everything::woocommerceGetCartInfo('small');
        break;

       case 'menu':
        echo '<nav class="top-nav-menu">';
        Everything::navMenu('top-bar-'.$device, null, 1);
        echo '</nav>';
        break;

       case 'lang_menu':
        if (count(icl_get_languages('skip_missing=0')) > 0) {
         echo '<nav class="top-nav-menu lang">';
         Everything::langMenu();
         echo '</nav>';
        }
        break;

       case 'mobile_toggle':
        if (Everything::to_('header/main_menu/visible')->value('mobile')) {
         echo '<a id="mobile-section-toggle" title="'.__('Menu', 'everything').'"><i class="icon-menu"></i></a>';
        }
        break;

      }
     }

    ?></div>
   </section>

  </div><!-- // .container -->

 <?php endif; ?>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
```

">

```
   <div class="usda-wrapper">
<div class="usda">
    <img src="http://www.cacaobox.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/USDA-Organic-Seal.png"  style="width:80px"/>
</div>
 </div>
   <div class="container">


 <div class="section">

  <span class="helper">
   <?php if (Everything::to_('header/main_menu/visible')->value('mobile') && !Everything::to_('header/top_bar/settings')->value('mobile_toggle')): ?>
    <a id="mobile-section-toggle" title="<?php _e('Menu', 'everything'); ?>"><i class="icon-menu"></i></a>
   <?php endif; ?>
  </span>

  <?php if (Everything::to_('header/style/settings')->value('centered')) echo '<div>'; ?>

   <h1 id="logo"<?php if (Everything::to('header/logo/shrunken', '__hidden')) echo ' class="shrunken"'; ?>>
    <?php $name = get_bloginfo('name', 'display'); ?>
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url('/')); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr($name); ?>" rel="home"><?php
     if (Everything::to_('header/logo/image')->property('image1x')) {
      echo Everything::to_('header/logo/image')->image()->alt($name)->html();
     } else {
      echo $name;
     }
    ?></a>
   </h1><!-- // #logo -->

   <?php if (Everything::to_('header/main_menu/visible')->value('desktop')): ?>
    <nav class="nav-menu main">
     <?php Everything::navMenu('main-desktop'); ?>
    </nav>
   <?php endif; ?>

  <?php if (Everything::to_('header/style/settings')->value('centered')) echo '</div>'; ?>

  <span class="helper">
   <?php echo Everything::woocommerceGetCartInfo('big', Everything::to('header/cart/visible', '__hidden', array())); ?>
  </span>

 </div>

 <div id="mobile-section">

  <?php if (Everything::to_('header/main_menu/visible')->value('mobile')): ?>
   <nav class="mobile-nav-menu main">
    <?php Everything::navMenu('main-mobile'); ?>
   </nav>
   <?php if (\Drone\Func::wpAssignedMenu('additional-mobile')): ?>
    <nav class="mobile-nav-menu additional">
     <?php Everything::navMenu('additional-mobile', null, 1); ?>
    </nav>
   <?php endif; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>

 </div>

</div><!-- // .container -->
```

```
<div class="container">

 <?php Everything::beginContent(); ?>
```

Comment: Which image? The site looks identical to me in Chrome and FF.

Comment: If you hit F12, you'll see some errors you need to address in the console.

Comment: its the image in the top right of firefox. so you see it in chrome?

Comment: I don't see an image in the top right in either Chrome or FF. What's the name of the image?

Comment: USDA-Organic-Seal.png

Comment: Chrome seems to be ignoring this code  <div class="usda-wrapper">
<div class="usda">
<img style="width:80px" src="http://www.cacaobox.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/USDA-Organic-Seal.png">
</div>
</div>

Comment: I don't see `USDA-Organic-Seal.png` in the DOM for Chrome or FF.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx38FFwehf2gLVhCaG5IMGR6b0E/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Building a minimally reduced test case is not only an effective debugging technique, it is also a a good way to demonstrate what you've done to solve the problem on your own. It's polite to the community for multiple reasons!

Comment: Perhaps FF is using some cached value of something? I've refreshed Chrome and FF and the image isn't there in the DOM, nor is it ever listed on the network tab.

Comment: Its strange now. If I go to other pages I sometimes see it.